# Can I apply tilak to coconut with first finger is that badluck?

Tags: belief, rituals, worship

Which finger to use, when applying **tilak** to coconut at an engagement ceremony?

Answer (score 1):

well you are **supposed** to apply tilak with ring finger but well using other fingers according to me does not bring any bad luck. Refer to this article- 
http://daily.bhaskar.com/news/JM-why-is-tilak-applied-with-ring-finger-2168156.html

Answer (score 1):

Apply tilak with ring finger at an engagement ceremony.

> Finger to be used for applying Tilak for different occasions:
>
> **1. Applying Tilak with ring finger(Anamika) gives peace.**
>
> We all experience a soothing effect at the time of sunrise. Perfect
>   peace can be experienced while sun rises. It is believed that at the
>   base of the ring finger is Sun. Thus applying Tilak with ring finger
>   provides peace. The ring finger should be used to apply Tilak to the
>   photos of  Hindu gods and goddesses.
>
> **2. Applying Tilak with middle finger(Madhyama) provides long life.**
>
> According to hindu mythology, it is believed that saturn is at the
>   base of the middle finger. Saturn is known as the protector of 
>   lifespan. Thus applying Tilak with middle finger provides long life.
>
> **3. Applying Tilak with thumb (Angushtha) provides strength.**
>
> Hindu mythology says that Venus is at the base of the thumb. Venus
>   represents health. Thumb is used for applying Tilak to men as it
>   symbolizes strength, health, etc.
>
> **4. Applying Tilak with INDEX finger(Tarjani) gives moksha.**
>
> At the base of the index finger is Jupiter. Tilak is applied with
>   index finger to dead body as it provides Moksha. Jupiter represents
>   immortality. Thus applying Tilak with index finger in other occasions
>   is considered as inauspicious. The index finger of the right hand
>   should be used for applying Tilak to the photos of  departed
>   ancestors.
>
> Tilak is applied at the space between two eyebrows known as Ajna
>   Chakra. Application of Chandan has very cooling effect and has
>   medicinal value. During heat, if one concentrates on Ajna Chakra , it
>   provides soothing and cooling effect. Tilak applied with ring finger
>   and thumb is very beneficial. Women should use ring finger for
>   applying Bindi. Women and men both should use unbroken rice mixed in
>   Red Chandan for Tilak as it symbolises peace and firmness of the
>   brain. There are 13 places on human body where Tilak can be placed but
>   only forehead is considered as noble. According to astrology, house of
>   Aries (Mesh Rashi)  is on forehead. Lord of  Mesh is Mars and its
>   colour is Red. This is the reason behind putting Red Chandan and
>   Sindoor as Tilak on the forehead.

[Source](https://admirableindia.wordpress.com/2015/08/02/do-you-know-which-finger-to-be-used-for-applying-tilak-for-different-occasions/)